# facebook. stop receiving responses

Tags: iphone, facebook-graph-api, httpresponse

I have such a problem. I have class, in which I make a call to facebook Graph API

```
[_facebook requestWithMethodName:@"fql.query"
                       andParams:params
                   andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                     andDelegate:self];
```

and two methods of delegate, that receive responces:

```
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
```

I need to make that way, to disable receive responces from facebook. How can I make it in a program way. Thanx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is the code which you are trying for Graph API

```
[_facebook requestWithMethodName:@"fql.query"  
                   andParams:params  
               andHttpMethod:@"POST"  
                 andDelegate:self];
```

This is not a graph API..

For graph Api:

```
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:"ANY GRAPH METHOD HERE"  
                 andParams:"DIFFERENT PARAMETERS YOU WANT TO PASS FOR THAT API"   
                 andHttpMethod:@"POST"  
                   andDelegate:self];
```

For Graph API's Check here:  http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/
and the API method is different for all the functions.

Comment: What question?  Can you tell me what are you trying to do.?

Comment: I'm starting some request to facebook. Send request. But while I'm waiting for response, I want not to receive response. How can I dissmiss my request?

Comment: getting user informattion. getting user info, friends list etc.

Comment: How to stop FBRequest? I can't find methods to stop it

Comment: Ok.  Try using requestWithGraphPath:@"me"

Comment: Well there is no such method available to STOP.  But you can use this method.  - (void)requestLoading:(FBRequest *)request;  //Which is called before sending request to the server..

Comment: No. I find out. We need to simply do [request release]; in that method we do [connection cancel] which will close connection to facebook.